# What are suitable transformer specs to use with LM1893 PLC modem?

Tags: transformer, power-line-communication

I'm trying to learn about PLC (I know the risks), so I want to start with the simplest circuit specified in the [LM1893](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=lm2893&fileType=pdf) datasheet to use on 220v AC powerline.
The transformer there doesn't have any specs, how can I choose a suitable transformer for that purpose?

Comment: Related: [What better options are there than the LM1893 for powerline communications?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/13520/8159)

Answer (score 2):

fig.7 on p.9 in the datasheet shows recommended transformers.

[image]

Notice also that LM1893 itself is obsolete (watermark in the datasheet).